# Execute a Simulink model one step using command line

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-engine, stateflow

I have given a Simulink model which I am controlling from my C++ program. From the Matlab engine I want to run the Simulink one step at a time for all of my given input. How can I run the simulation from my C++ program one step at a time?

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7267-what-is-the-best-way-to-execute-a-simulink-model-step-by-step-interactively-from-matlab for various approaches.